# Which design pattern to avoid if/else

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm developing a code where I need to consume a json message from a queue and mapping to a java class to verify some values field and decide what flow/process i have to do.

```
if (car.getName.equals("Audi") && car.getDoors >= 2){
   //do some proccess in other class
} 
if (car.getName.equals("Opel") && car.getDoors < 2){
   //do some proccess in other class
}
if (car.getEnginePower > 1500){
   //do some proccess in other class
}
```

The problem is obvious, i need always to add a new if statement when a new rule in business logic is added.

What is the best behaviour design pattern to avoid this if/else strategy to try not Open–Closed principle.

Comment: "I need always to add a new if statement when a new rule in business logic is added." Why is that a problem? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Strategy pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think it's inelegant and costly in the future to maintain if you have a lot of rules like this.

Comment: You can delegate this logic inside car class. You can use polymorphism based on the car class to select which logic has to be executed. You can inject these rules instead of having them hard-coded like this. It's all a matter of opinion.

Comment: For rules that don't have a specific guaranteed pattern -- you show several different kinds of rules here -- there's not necessarily a solution that's going to be better than this.  There may be other solutions, but they're not necessarily going to be better.